# cos(1/3 arccos(x) )

Tags: polynomials

let $y(x) = \cos(3 \arccos x)$, then $y(x) = 4x^3 - 3x$.  (Chebychev poly),  My question is CAN $ \cos( \frac{1}{3} \arccos x )$ be expressed as an alternate function of $x$?  This would change the face of the cubic formula forever.  Making it a theorem, possibly!

Comment: What's an alternate function?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I think the OP is thinking that is there another way to express it, and still be equivalent.

Comment: Correct, G.  If cos(3arcosx) = 4x^3 - 3x, then My question is: What is cos(1/3 arcos x) = ?   Say for  example  = square-root( x^3 - 2)  + square-root (x^3 + 2)   for instance....   WHAT is the answer?  A Macclauren series kind of works, even a first order Macclauren is nice, but NOT EXACT!

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(3 \arccos y) =   x$, and thus
$x = 4y^3 - 3y$.

Comment: Can't solve for y(x) in terms of x because 4y^3 - 3y is a cubic.